# How to prove: $E(|tr(x^Tww^Ty)|^k)\leq \|yx^T\|_2^k E(tr(x^Tww^Tx)^k)$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability, statistics, random-variables

How to prove:

$$E(|tr(x^Tww^Ty)|^k)\leq \|yx^T\|_2^k E(tr(x^Tww^Tx)^k)$$, where $k$ is a positive integer,  $x,y$ are fixed vectors, each entry in $w$ i.i.d. follows from an standard norm distribution, $E$ is the expectation on $w$, $\|\|_2$ is a matrix 2 norm, $||$ is to get an absolute value, and $tr()$ means the trace.

**Thank people who help to point out some errors in the original question, now I make some supplements as follow**

I extracted and reformulated the question based on the last 7 lines on the right column in page 4 of pape http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.4626v1.pdf , where the $l2$ norm of $x,y$ should also be $1$.

Comment: It looks like that both $x^Tww^Ty$ and $x^Tww^Tx$ are scalars, then why do we need "$\text{tr}$"?

Comment: yes, honestly, this is from a paper. I think some property of **tr** may be used to derive this inequality.

Comment: I mean, if they are scalars, then "$\text{tr}$" are superfluous.

Comment: yes, you are right.

Comment: All right, then I don't think this inequality holds. For example, let's say everything is scalar. Take $x = y = 1/2$, $k = 1$, then the left side is $E(w^2/4)$, which is strictly greater than the right side $E(w^2/4)/4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, I make some changes after the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26013/discussion-between-zhanxiong-and-olivia).